# How to know that the data on the clipboard is ready to be used?

Tags: vb.net, clipboard

My code copies a table, processes the copied data, copies another table, processes the copied data and so on ...

The problem is that sometimes some tables have a lot of data that take a long time to be copied, causing an error in the try/catch block.

Is there a way to start processing the copied data only after the data is ready on the clipboard?

```
   Private Sub Copy
      Clipboard.Clear()
            Try
                Win32.SetCursorPos(200,200)
                Win32.mouse_event(Win32.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                Win32.mouse_event(Win32.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                SendKeys.SendWait("^C")
            Catch ex As Exception
                Msgbox (ex.message)
            End Try


            'PROCESS THE COPIED DATA
        Try
            Dim clip() As String
            Dim col() As String
            clip = Clipboard.GetText().Split(Environment.NewLine)
            col = clip(i).Split(vbTab)
            'I test the data to see if it interests me
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


     Clipboard.Clear()
            Try
                Win32.SetCursorPos(600,200)
                Win32.mouse_event(Win32.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                Win32.mouse_event(Win32.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                SendKeys.SendWait("^C")
            Catch ex As Exception
                Msgbox (ex.message)
            End Try



            'PROCESS THE COPIED DATA


     Clipboard.Clear()
            Try
                Win32.SetCursorPos(400,200)
                Win32.mouse_event(Win32.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                Win32.mouse_event(Win32.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                SendKeys.SendWait("^C")
            Catch ex As Exception
                Msgbox (ex.message)
            End Try


            'PROCESS THE COPIED DATA


    End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect an XY Problem here.  What are you trying to accomplish here?  What is the source of the data and what do you do with the processed data.  IOW, provide some context.

Comment: I get data from a 3rd party software, a trader Software (developed in delphi). It allows me to get the data from its tables by selecting them and clicking ctrl + c. Then I scroll through the table to get the data that interests me and then I start doing the same with the second table, third ...

Comment: I updated my code to show the way I use the data I got.

Comment: It seems a hacky way to get data but if that's the only avenue open to you then you have to use it. The obvious solution seems to be to write a method to get the data and, in that method, write a loop that attempts to get the repeatedly until no exception is thrown, pausing momentarily between attempts.

Comment: It's the only way I have to get the data...Do you suggest, for example, putting a 'Goto' in Catch to return to the beginning of the Try block and a Thread.sleep? –

Comment: How about just pasting the data into a text file and then read it from there.  Or maybe into Excel.  That eliminates the timing issues and frees you from mouse manipulation.

Comment: No, no `GoTo`. Not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a loop as per @jmcilhinney 's comment. No `GoTo`. Set the number of tries in the `If ErrorCount > 3 Then`. You were repeating your code. Usually not a good idea for maintenance. The only thing that changed was the left and top, so I passed those as parameters. The display of the message box will provide the pause. Your ProcessCopiedData should probably be a separate sub called from the Copy sub.

```
Private Sub Copy(left As Integer, top As Integer)
    Dim ErrorCount As Integer
    Do
        Clipboard.Clear()
        Try
            Win32.SetCursorPos(left, top)
            Win32.mouse_event(Win32.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            Win32.mouse_event(Win32.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            SendKeys.SendWait("^C")
            ErrorCount = 0
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorCount += 1
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        If ErrorCount > 3 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Exceeded # of Trys.")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Loop Until ErrorCount < 1
    'Process Copied Data
End Sub
```

Usage...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Copy(200, 200)
    Copy(600, 200)
    Copy(400, 200)
End Sub
```